# how to show 2nd screen composable in 1st screen

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i have 2 screen MainActivity and MainActivity2 i want to show MainActivity2 ui in 1st screen but it is not visible only Hello pirates are visible to you

```
    package com.pine

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Column() {
                Text("Hello pirates")
                MainActivity2()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

2nd screen

```
package com.pine

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import com.bluepine.ui.theme.BluepineClubTheme
import com.example.bluepine.module.offerpage.ChallengeCard

class MainActivity2 : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
                Text("This is com.pine.MainActivity2")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the activity from the compose code.
Some thong like this:

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen() {
    Column() {
        Text("Hello pirates")
        SecondScreen()
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {
    Text("This is com.pine.MainActivity2")
}
```

and now you an use it in the activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FirstScreen()
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity2 : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SecondScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Activities aren't composable functions, so you can't pass an activity inside another activity to see its content.
And generally speaking the compose application is designed to be used in a single-activity architecture with no fragments. So you don't need to create multiple activities if you want to display several screens .

Don't create another activity , just create a @composable function for your second screen and pass it to your  MainActivity

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen() {
    Text("Hello pirates")
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {
    Text("This is Second Screen")
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Column(){
                FirstScreen()
                SecondScreen()
            }

        }
    }
}
```